# Having trouble separating urls.py

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Hello I'm a newbie in Django.

I'm creating a blog app for practice and I wanted to separate the urls that relates to the blog application from the urls that relates to the other applications.

Since there are many blog-related url patterns, I just included in the main `urls.py`. 
Here is my urls.py:

**My_Project/My_Project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Blog
    url(r'^$', include('app_blog.urls'), name='app_blog'),

    # Admin
    url(r'^admin/$', include(admin.site.urls), name='admin_page'),
    ......
```

**My_Project/app_blog/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Index page
    url(r'^index/$', index_page),

    # User page
    url(r'^user/(?P<pk>\d+)/', UserDetail.as_view(), name='user_detail'),
    ......
```

So I expected that when I navigate to "www.example.com/index" the browser would show the `index_page` view and for "www.example.com/user/1", it will show the user detail view for user with id equal to 1.

For some reason, however, it shows the 404 page not found error for both pages.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. `name` parameter is for a single url pattern. Remove it from this line in My_Project/My_Project/urls.py
2. The regex pattern should not be '^$'. Instead just plain `''`.

   ```
   url(r'', include('app_blog.urls'))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
# Blog
url(r'^$', include('app_blog.urls'), name='app_blog'),
     ~~~
```

You are restricting your url to an empty path, that means everything that is not an empty path will not be matched against `app_blog.urls`.
Do this instead:

```
# Blog
url(r'^', include('app_blog.urls')),
```